# Show/Hide multiple buttons with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, router

I'm trying to show/hide different buttons with ReactJS for the purpose of multiple view option and I'm stuck.

I'm running some queries based on `user input` with `reactJS`. I want to make it possible for the user to have multiple views of the same query and for that my Idea was to use `react-router` and navigate between pages ( as views ) with the help of buttons. 
So far I understood that it's possible to save the user input into variable and use it with the `router`, but first I wanted to know how to create buttons after the user submits his input.

My Idea was to create the button and hide it and then unhide it from the call Function. But I don't know how can I change the style of other button not the that that was clicked.

If this isn't good practice how can I create new button from within the function that is called `onSubmit` ?

My Code:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
event.preventDefault();
const nBtn = this.otherBtn.value;

//hidden to false -- how ?


//run query
}

 render() {
return(
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
   <FormGroup>
   <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search for xy" inputRef={(ref) => {this.xy= ref}}  />
   </FormGroup>
   <Button className="searchXY" type="submit" bsStyle="success">Search</Button>
   </form>
   <br />
   <Button className="btnRouter" id='testBtn' type="submit" bsStyle="danger" hiden={true} inputRef={(ref) => {this.otherBtn= ref}}  >See results as abcd </Button>
  );
}
```

Comment: Confused by the way you have asked your question. Would you be able to re think your wording?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm thinking you are wanting to show the `See result as abcd` Button after you have submitted your Form... If so - you may want to call `this.setState` in your handleSubmit and make use of [Reacts conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) To show/hide your button based on the value of `this.state.showButton`

```js
constructor (props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = { showbutton: false }
  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
}

handleSubmit () {
  this.setState({ showButton: true })
}

render () {
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={ this.handleSubmit }>
        <input type="text" />
        <button type="submit" />
      </form>
      {this.state.showButton ? <button>See as abcd</button> : null}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Yes this helps me to create a second button after the form is submitted! I imagine that I can use the newly made buttons to link them to the `router` ?

Comment: @Richard If you are using react-router then the button would most likely need to be a `<Link to={'your route'}>See as abcd</Link>` see the docs : https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

Comment: and do you know how could I get the value of `<FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search for xy" inputRef={(ref) => {this.xy= ref}}  />` and run different query, when the user press the new button which I will made with `<Link to={'your route'}>See as abcd</Link>` ?

Comment: I would guess that if you had a `onClick` method on your new button and called a `differentMethod` on that click you'd have reference to `this.xy` from that method and you'd be able to do something like `this.xy.value` and handle it from there.

Comment: I will try that. Thank you.